# Renaming a file download from a different origin

Tags: javascript, html, same-origin-policy

I know that you cannot rename a file using the download attribute on an `<a>` if the file is from another origin as mentioned [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a).

> This attribute is only honored for links to resources with the
>   same-origin.

I made a script that give me the option to download MP4s that are being played back on a site, but most of the time the source of the MP4 is such that I can't name the download.

What alternative methods exists to rename a download from another origin? Can the file be cached, then renamed, and the user given the option to save it?

Current code to download:

```
function downloadVideo(uri, name) {
  var link = document.createElement("a");
  link.download = name;
  link.href = uri;
  link.click();
}
```

Comment: How is file retrieved to offer for download? Using `<a>` element?

Comment: @guest271314 Added the code to my question, I should have done that in the first place.

Comment: Is file able to be retrieved from server using `XMLHttpRequest()`?

Comment: @guest271314 I am not sure how I would go about that. I will get back to you on that one once I puzzle out the process for that. The video source is a link to an MP4 file with an auth token as a parameter. `http://somesite.com/somevideo.mp4?someToken`

Comment: @guest271314 It does not look like I can. The resource is on `http` while the page is on `https` and the AJAX request will not go through with the mixed content.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?

Comment: @marcusshep I never did :(

Comment: @DouglasGaskell If you have any information at all it'd be greatly appreciated. lol.